How do I get jsconfig.json working for a chrome extension on vscode?
I just created a jsconfig.json file with the line below at the root of my project:
{"typeAcquisition": {"include": ["chrome"]}}
My intellisense for chrome api still doesnt seem to work. Does anyone know what might be the problem? Do I need to add something else to my jsconfig for vscode to be able to read it?

However, according to VS Code Docs, there isn't an option typeAcquisition in jsconfig.json. Only tsconfig.json supports that.

Although you are not using TypeScript, VS Code knows tsconfig.json. Use this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["chorme"]
  }
}

Run:
pnpm add -D @types/chrome



do you know how I might get intellisense for chrome extensions working then? Ive seen a few other answers on stackoverflow all telling people to add this line in their jsconfig file.

@RyanBae answer edited
